# Using one() on two IDs to run once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons and what I want is no matter which one is clicked, the function should execute only once. So this is what I have tried, but it does not work because if I press `#first` button and it runs the function once, but if I press `#second` button it runs the function again. Clearly that is how it is meant to be with `one()`.

```
$('#first, #second').one('click', function(e) {
  dosomething();
})
```

This actually does what it should be doing, please someone point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: you can achieve this using a boolean value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) restrict handler to executed at most once per element. thus the expected behaviour

You can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove event handler

```
$('#first, #second').one('click', function(e) {
  $('#first, #second').off('click');
})
```

Comment: Superb! Works like charm and I wanted to stick with JQuery. So, this is the correct answer for my query.

Comment: No need to use `.one()` you can use `.on()` and then `.off()`

Comment: @Tanmay You are right, this works for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can unbind the clickhandler after it was invoked using .off() like

```js
$("#first, #second")
  .on("click.onlyonce", function(e) {
    console.info("click");
    // do whatever
    $("#first, #second").off("click.onlyonce");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first">First</button>
<button id="second">Second</button>
```